# Удаление элемента при условии ООП js

Tags: javascript, ооп

При запуске у нас есть 10 шаров. Когда мы кликаем, то спауним новый шар. Требуется реализовать удаление этого шара, если его радиус больше 70
P.s Если не сложно, то реализуйте через ф-ю и объясните как все работает, пожалуйста.(Работал через splice, но безуспешно)

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}


var userRadius = prompt('Введите размер шарика');
var radius;
var canvas, ctx, balls, idTimer;
TBall = new Class({
  initialize: function(pX, pY) {
    this.posX = pX; //позиция шарика по X
    this.posY = pY; //позиция шарика по Y
    //цвет шарика, формируется случайным образом
    this.colBall = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ')';
    // радиус шарика, случайное число от 5 
    this.rBall = 5 + Math.random() * userRadius;
    radius = this.rBall;
    console.log(radius);
  },
  posX: 0,
  posY: 0,
  colBall: "rgb(0,0,0)",
  rBall: 0,
  colorBall: function(ctx) {
    // формируем градиентную заливку для шарика
    with(this) {
      var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(posX + rBall / 4,
        posY - rBall / 6, rBall / 8, posX, posY, rBall);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
      gradient.addColorStop(0.85, colBall);
      return gradient;
    }
  },
  draw: function(ctx) {
    // рисуем шарик на canvas
    with(this) {
      ctx.fillStyle = colorBall(ctx);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(posX, posY, rBall, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
});

function drawBack(ctx, col1, col2, w, h) {
  // закрашиваем канвас градиентным фоном
  ctx.save();
  var g = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h);
  g.addColorStop(1, col1);
  g.addColorStop(0, col2);
  ctx.fillStyle = g;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.restore();
}
// инициализация работы
function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //рисуем фон
    drawBack(ctx, '#202020', '#aaa', canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //создаем 10 шариков, заноси их в массив и выводим на canvas
    balls = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      var item = new TBall(10 + Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30),
        10 + Math.random() * (canvas.height - 30));
      item.draw(ctx);
      balls.push(item);
    }
  }
}

// создаем новый шарик по щелчку мыши, добавляем его в массив шариков и рисуем его
function goInput(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var item = new TBall(x, y);
  item.draw(ctx);
  balls.push(item);
}

var number;

function move(userNumber) {
  number = parseInt(userNumber);
  console.log(number);
  idTimer = setInterval('moveBall();', 50);
}

function moveBall() {

  //Переменные, которые помогают менять направление
  var a, b, c, d;

  //реализация движения шариков, находящихся в массиве balls
  drawBack(ctx, '#202020', '#aaa', canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var rand1 = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
  var rand2 = Math.random() * 2 - 4;

  if (number == 4) {
    number = getRandomInt(0, 3);
  }

  switch (number) {

    case 0: //up
      a = rand1;
      d = a;
      b = rand2;
      c = b;
      break;

    case 1: //down
      a = -rand1;
      d = a;
      b = -rand2;
      c = b;
      break;

    case 2: //right
      a = -rand2;
      d = a;
      b = rand1;
      c = b;
      break;

    case 3: //left
      a = rand2;
      d = a;
      b = rand1;
      c = b;
      break;

    case 5:
      b = rand1;
      a = rand2;
      d = -a;
      c = -b;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i) {
    balls[i].posX = balls[i].posX + a || d;
    balls[i].posY = balls[i].posY + b || c;
    balls[i].draw(ctx);
    if ((balls[i].posX > canvas.width) || (balls[i].posX < 0) || (balls[i].posY < 0))
      balls.splice(i, 1);
    else
      i++;
  }


}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Canvas & Mootools</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" onclick="goInput(event);">
     </canvas>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Up" onclick="move(0);">
    <input type="button" value="Down" onclick="move(1);">
    <input type="button" value="Right" onclick="move(2);">
    <input type="button" value="Left" onclick="move(3);">
    <input type="button" value="Random" onclick="move(4);">
    <input type="button" value="Chaos" onclick="move(5);">
    <input type="button" value="Стоп" onclick="clearInterval(idTimer);">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Требуется реализовать удаление этого шара, если его радиус больше 70" Правильно ли я вас понимаю - вам нужно удалить шар если его радиус получился больше 70 так? Именно тот, который будет нарисован при нажатии ?

Comment: Да, все верно. Нажимаю, происходит проверка, и, если его радиус больше 70, то он удаляется

Comment: Тогда как насчет варианта, когда вы проверяете радиус до рисования и просто не рисуете его, если его радиус выше 70. Будет выглядеть так, как будто ничего не произошло. Можно например в Initialize перед console.log провести проверку полученного радиуса. Если он не верный то инициализация вернет null, на который можно реагировать в goInput() и init()

Comment: Вариант хороший, но по тз требуется сделать именно их удаление(чтобы лопались)

Comment: Но это будет происходить очень быстро (нарисовалось, проверилось, и удалилось - в реальности будет выглядеть так как будто шара и не было). Разве что если анимацию поставить на создание и удаление, тогда это имеет смысл

Comment: Планировалось, что тот код, который мне помогут написать я поставлю на интервал 1сек

Comment: Просто в этом случае вам стоит знать что канвас это просто "кадр" который вам надо отрисовывать. Если вы "удалите" шар после того как его нарисовали, то под ним вы получите "дырку" в фоне - т.е. в вашем градиенте. А отсюда следует что после удаления нужна новая отрисовка кадра согласно существующему массиву balls (чтобы заного нарисовать фон, и нарисовать все шары где они были минус тот что был удален). Поэтому если есть пред условие - то проще фигуру "не рисовать". А если надо организовать удаление - то ваш код надо модифицировать для перерисовки сцены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось не слишком красиво ( и не по ООП тем более), но общий принцип я тут выразил. Есть цикл обновления канваса, есть добавление рисунка на канвас. Если условие не сходится - то рисунок поялвяется в периоде 2 секунд (до обновления канваса) и затем удаляется как не корректный. Код этот требует осознанного видоизменения (+ я не слишком хорошо знаком с канвасом).

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}


var userRadius = 80;
var RADIUSRESTRICTION = 70;
var radius;
var canvas, ctx, balls, idTimer;
var stopUpdating = false;
TBall = new Class({
  initialize: function(pX, pY) {
    this.posX = pX; //позиция шарика по X
    this.posY = pY; //позиция шарика по Y
    //цвет шарика, формируется случайным образом
    this.colBall = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ')';
    // радиус шарика, случайное число от 5 
    this.rBall = 5 + Math.random() * userRadius;
    // radius = this.rBall; //неясно зачем это тут
    console.log(this.rBall);
    // Если шар не соответсвует нужному радиусу - помечаем его как неверный
    // (хотя по правильному было бы вернуть null вместо объекта)
    if (this.rBall >= RADIUSRESTRICTION) {
      this.isCorrect = false;
    }
  },
  posX: 0,
  posY: 0,
  // переменная которая следит за "правильностью" шара.
  isCorrect: true,
  colBall: "rgb(0,0,0)",
  rBall: 0,
  colorBall: function(ctx) {
    // формируем градиентную заливку для шарика
    with(this) {
      var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(posX + rBall / 4,
        posY - rBall / 6, rBall / 8, posX, posY, rBall);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
      gradient.addColorStop(0.85, colBall);
      return gradient;
    }
  },
  draw: function() {
    // рисуем шарик на canvas если он корректный
    with(this) {
      ctx.fillStyle = colorBall(ctx);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(posX, posY, rBall, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
});

function drawBack(ctx, col1, col2, w, h) {
  // закрашиваем канвас градиентным фоном
  ctx.save();
  var g = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h);
  g.addColorStop(1, col1);
  g.addColorStop(0, col2);
  ctx.fillStyle = g;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.restore();
}
// инициализация работы
function init() {
  balls = [];
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  //создаем 10 шариков, заноси их в массив 
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var item = new TBall(10 + Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30),
      10 + Math.random() * (canvas.height - 30));
    // тут мы увеличиваем счетчик если шар нам не "подошел" 
    // по радиусу, чтобы всегда рисовалость 10 шаров.
    balls.push(item);
  }
  updateScene(canvas);
  // Ставим бесконечный таймер ( с условием выхода) каждые 2 секунды он обновляет состояние (для тестирования поведения - можно поставить и меньше)
  var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    updateScene(canvas)
    if (stopUpdating) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }
  }, 2000);
}

function updateScene(canvas) {
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Store the current transformation matrix
    ctx.save();

    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Restore the transform
    ctx.restore();
    //рисуем фон
    drawBack(ctx, '#202020', '#aaa', canvas.width, canvas.height);


    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
      balls[i].draw();
    }
    balls = balls.filter((item) => item.isCorrect);
    console.log(balls.length);
  }
}

// создаем новый шарик по щелчку мыши, добавляем его в массив шариков и рисуем его
function goInput(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var item = new TBall(x, y);
  balls.push(item);
  item.draw(); // на самом деле это неправильно, но добавлено для наглядности
}

var number;

function move(userNumber) {
  number = parseInt(userNumber);
  console.log(number);
  idTimer = setInterval('moveBall();', 50);
}

function moveBall() {

  //Переменные, которые помогают менять направление
  var a, b, c, d;

  //реализация движения шариков, находящихся в массиве balls
  drawBack(ctx, '#202020', '#aaa', canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var rand1 = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
  var rand2 = Math.random() * 2 - 4;

  if (number == 4) {
    number = getRandomInt(0, 3);
  }

  switch (number) {

    case 0: //up
      a = rand1;
      d = a;
      b = rand2;
      c = b;
      break;

    case 1: //down
      a = -rand1;
      d = a;
      b = -rand2;
      c = b;
      break;

    case 2: //right
      a = -rand2;
      d = a;
      b = rand1;
      c = b;
      break;

    case 3: //left
      a = rand2;
      d = a;
      b = rand1;
      c = b;
      break;

    case 5:
      b = rand1;
      a = rand2;
      d = -a;
      c = -b;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i) {
    balls[i].posX = balls[i].posX + a || d;
    balls[i].posY = balls[i].posY + b || c;
    balls[i].draw(ctx);
    if ((balls[i].posX > canvas.width) || (balls[i].posX < 0) || (balls[i].posY < 0))
      balls.splice(i, 1);
    else
      i++;
  }


}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Canvas & Mootools</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" onclick="goInput(event);">
     </canvas>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Up" onclick="move(0);">
    <input type="button" value="Down" onclick="move(1);">
    <input type="button" value="Right" onclick="move(2);">
    <input type="button" value="Left" onclick="move(3);">
    <input type="button" value="Random" onclick="move(4);">
    <input type="button" value="Chaos" onclick="move(5);">
    <input type="button" value="Стоп" onclick="clearInterval(idTimer);">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```